# jquery update captcha

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I trying to update captcha with js and ASP.NET MVC3 razor. I found this solution:
View:

```
<div id ="CaptchaDiv"> <img alt="Captcha" id="Captchaimg" src="@Url.Action("GetCaptcha")" style="" /></div>  <input type="button"  value="Refresh" onclick=" return GetCaptcha()" />
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetCaptcha ()
        {
            FileContentResult img = null;
            int res = 0;
            MemoryStream mem = Metods.CaptchaImage( out res);
            Session["Captcha"] = res;
          img = this.File(mem.GetBuffer(), "image/Jpeg");
            return img;
        }
```

JS:

```
function GetCaptcha()
 {
     $('Captchaimg').attr('src', '/Account/GetCaptcha?' + new Date().getTime());
 }
```

But: it doesn't work. JS runs  successfuly. But controller action doesn't run. What is wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your selector `$('Captchaimg')` must be wrong. If you're using id, it should be `$('#Captchaimg')`.

Also what does trigger this action? I'd use:

```
$('#Captchaimg').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', '/Account/GetCaptcha?' + new Date().getTime());
});
```

And I'd change id's to lowercase.

Comment: Thanks, My inattention will kill me sometime